# How to separate the javafx GUI structures and its implementation?

Tags: java, javafx

For example this code:

```
public class VendorManagementSystem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox main_pane = new VBox(15);
        main_pane.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        Button addItem_mainPane = new Button("Add Item");
        addItem_mainPane.setPrefWidth(120);
        Button cancelation_button = new Button("Close");
        cancelation_button.setPrefWidth(120);

        main_pane.getChildren().addAll(addItem_mainPane,sellItem_mainPane,cancelation_button);
        main_pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(main_pane);

        primaryStage.setHeight(450);
        primaryStage.setWidth(650);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Vendor Management System");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

Then I wanna to separate this in another class:

```
cancelation_button.setOnAction(e->{
      primaryStage.close();

});
```

I tried to create another class and inherit the javafx class to create the implementation in another class:

```
public class ControlsImplementation extends VendorManagementSystem{

   cancelation_button.setOnAction(e->{

              primaryStage.close();

        });
```

}

but it doesnt work i got those errors:

> error: < identifier > expected
>          cancelation_button.setOnAction(e->{
>
> error: < identifier > expected
>          cancelation_button.setOnAction(e->{
>
> error: illegal start of type
>               });

Any suggestion how to separate the javafx gui structures and the controls implementation.

Comment: Those are compile errors. It just means you have the syntax wrong. (And no-one can possibly help you fix them without actually seeing the code you wrote.)

Comment: it is not about the compiler error my idea is how to separate the gui structures and the controls implementation  @James_D

Comment: So what is the part of your question that starts "I tried to create another class and inherit the javafx class..." included for? I assumed that you thought that would be an approach that would help you achieve what you were trying to do (though I'm not sure how), and that you were unable to implement it. If that's not the case, why is that part of the question there?

Comment: I just wanted to mention what i tried with no result. @James_D

Comment: But all you're saying is that you tried something and it didn't work. Presumably you want help getting it to work: my point is no-one can help you fix it unless you show us the code that doesn't work. It's not at all clear  what you're trying to do anyway: you say you want to separate some code into another class, but the code you say you want to move isn't actually a part of the code you currently have. (And it's not clear what that code is supposed to do.) You need to clarify this question.

Comment: the code is already modified any suggestion @James_D

Comment: Uh, sure, see answer. I'm not meaning to be patronizing here, but you seem to be pretty new to Java (you posted code in which you're trying to invoke methods on objects from outside any method, which is pretty basic syntax, and you don't seem to have understood inheritance yet). Are you sure you are at a point where you want to try to use a complex framework and implement pretty complex design patterns with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separate classes for the view and for the controller. You should make both of these independent of the `Application` class, which has responsibility for starting the application and managing its lifecycle:

View class:

```
public class View extends VBox {

    private final Controller controller ;

    public View(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller ;
        buildUI();
    }

    private void buildUI() {
        setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));

        Button addItem = new Button("Add Item");
        addItem.setPrefWidth(120);
        Button cancelation = new Button("Close");
        cancelation.setPrefWidth(120);
        cancelation.setOnAction(e -> controller.exit(this));

        getChildren().addAll(addItem, /* sellItem, */ cancelation);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public class Controller {

    public void exit(Node view) {
        view.getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
}
```

Application class:

```
public class VendorManagementSystem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Controller controller = new Controller();
        View view = new View(controller);

        Scene scene = new Scene(view);
        primaryStage.setHeight(450);
        primaryStage.setWidth(650);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Vendor Management System");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Obviously in a real application you would have a data model in addition to the view and controller classes.

You can vary the relationship between the view and the controller according to how you want things set up, e.g. instead of giving the view a reference to the controller, you could give the controller a reference to the view, define a `getCancelationButton()` method in the view, and call `getCancelationButton().setOnAction(...)` in the controller. It just depends which variant of MVC you are trying to implement.